# can't receive message send by postMessage method on webView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, postmessage

There are two page:a.html,b.html.

In a.html,I send a message to b.html using window.postMessage()

```
<input type="text" name=""><input type="button" value="search">
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="url"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function () {
    var mapWindow = window.open('d.html?s=' + $('input[type="text"]').val() + '&nw=1');
    setTimeout(function () {
        mapWindow.postMessage('hello', 'http://192.168.199.191:8080');
    },10000);
})
window.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage,false);
function receiveMessage(e) {
    // if (e.origin ! = ) return;
    $('#name').text(e.data.placeName);
    $('#url').text(e.data.imgUrl);
}
</script>
```

in b.html,I listen to message event:

```
window.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage,false);
function receiveMessage(e) {
    $('#log').text(e.data);
    e.source.postMessage(message,e.origin);
}
```

Code on browser will show "hello" on #log element,but when I put the page in app,a.html will receive itself message,but b.html can't show 'hello',it doesn't receive message from a.html

Why in webView the code can't work?

Comment: The message won't flow from `WebView` to `WebView`. I'm guessing you are using 2 to load a.html and b.html.

Comment: what's '2 to load'? I don't understand what's mean.In my app,add 'nw=1' after the url will open a new tab.

Comment: 2 tab? It must be in one tab?Is it mean that I can only use iframe to achieve it?